# How can i set the command of a button within a DataTemplate to the data context of the parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listbox which binds to a observable collection in my view model (the user controls data context).

```
DeviceDetector driveDetector;
public DriveSelector()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    driveDetector = DeviceDetector.Instance;
    DataContext = driveDetector;
}
```

This is my code for my listbox

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding DriveCollection}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="70" Style="{StaticResource DriveButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SimpleMethod}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Style="{StaticResource DriveImageStyle}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DriveLabelStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I have implemented ICommand and when i bind to the command outside of the listbox like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SimpleMethod}"/>
```

Everything is fine. However when i try to bind the command to the button's inside the listbox's datatemplate i get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SimpleMethod' property not found on 'object' ''DriveInfo'
>   (HashCode=6377350)'. BindingExpression:Path=SimpleMethod;
>   DataItem='DriveInfo' (HashCode=6377350); target element is 'Button'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I can see that the datacontext of the button is to the model and so the method 'SimpleMethod' cannot be found. Is there a way that i can bind the command to the datacontext of the listbox itself?

Comment: You could write a custom behavior for your button. This way you'll bind it to your button. Don't know, when should this method be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the window or page top level DataContext like this:

```
 <Button Content="{StaticResource Whatever}"
      DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
      Command="{Binding SimpleMethod}" />
```

Comment: It's enough to get `DataContext` of `ListBox`. Also, you forgot `Path=SimpleCommand` in your binding.  This should be an accepted answer after imho. Small note: either remove `CommandParameter` (OP seems don't need it) or move it **before** `Command` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/336258/1997232) why it is important).

Comment: @Sinatr, thanks for the tip. But I don't use `Path` in my command that I took this code from, and it works fine.

Comment: You are right, for some weird reasons (sorry for my previous comment then) I haven't seen you are reassigning `DataContext`. Don't do that. Rather use `RelativeSource` in `Command` binding itself: `Command="{Binding DataContext.SimpleMethod, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"`.

Comment: @Sinatr, what is the reasoning for that? If I reassign the context then I could use it on any number of attributes without having to do RelativeSource on each, right? Is it a performance/efficiency issue?

Comment: Good question. For me not touching `DataContext` in the world of data templates is an axiom. Perhaps to avoid situation like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5155852/1997232). Can't say anything about performance.

Answer (score 0):

What is owner of SimpleMethod? DataContext or item of collection? I suspect that DataContext. Move SimpleMethod to item class from DataContext class. Or use RelativeSource like this [Bind to ItemsControl's DataContext from inside an ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511516/bind-to-itemscontrols-datacontext-from-inside-an-itemtemplate)

Answer (score 0):

How i managed to solve my problem:

Firstly i created a static resource of my view model. Then bound it to my datacontext in xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles;component/Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:DeviceSelectorViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" x:Name="myVM" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="myViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Which allowed me to then change the source of the command to the (static resource) view model like so:

```
<Button Width="70" Style="{StaticResource DriveButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SimpleCommand, Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" >
```

Thanks for the replies!